# Landscape Page Turn in Silverlight ( vertical )

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, landscape

i am looking for [page turn Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/content/samples/1.0/page-turn/default.html) in landscape mode.
Or can we show PDF file Silverlight?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to do using http://page-flip.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive post on [implementing page turn techniques here](http://www.cynergysystems.com/blogs/page/rickbarraza?entry=the_secret_behind_the_page).

You could should PDF using an iframe in Silverlight 3 or using the Html control in Silverlight 4.